# Bin directory in ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page using Visual studio. and I added some references which works perfectly but there is no Bin Directory in the project directory. What Should I do?

Comment: have you tried building your solution?

Comment: Do you created Web Project or Web Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bin folder is not mandatory - if you're using dynamic compilation, and don't reference any external 3rd-party libraries, it is perferctly normal that you wont have a bin folder